# Calling Rest ful web service by giving an input of XML file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

i am using spring integration and have below code.

```
    @ServiceActivator
    public void postHibuFeedToClosely(Message<Document> input) {

        Document payload = input.getPayload();

    }
```

here "input" has payload. payload has an XML. Now i need to pass the XML as an input to rest ful webservice.

End point is :  `https://somthing.com/someLocation/status`

Request : `POST`

How can i get xml content from pay load?
How can i call the rest ful webservice using jersey?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring Webservices for this. There are adapters in spring-integration-http and the documentation is rather good. The Document payload will be automatically transformed, you don't need to do anything special for that, provided that you want to send the actual document over as is.

You should start [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/http/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/http-outbound-config.xml) I think.